# Google Keep with multiple categories?

Tags: google-keep

I've recently started using Google Keep for storing quick notes on my phone and personal laptop.

I'd like to start using this at work also on my desktop machine, however I don't want my work notes to be mixed in with personal notes.

Is there a way of splitting the notes onto seperate pages/categories so that my personal ones aren't displayed at work?

Comment: You could use your work account instead of your personal account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install This 
    https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/category-tabs-for-google/dlahcjmefibiedeecoegjilekaebchhl?hl=en

And keep all your personal Notes in one color, and select the other colors so that your personal items do not show up. I know this is really irritating, but google wants us to feel that way it seems :)

Comment: It seems that this extension screws up the keyboard shortcuts though. E.e. the compose shortcut `c` is not working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Now Google Keep include labels to help to organize notes. For further details see [Organize notes with labels - Google Keep Help](https://support.google.com/keep/answer/6191044?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

There's not currently any way to hide notes without deleting or archiving them. You can't split the notes into categories or folders, but you can differentiate the notes by color-coding them or adding common titles.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Catagories for Google Keep from https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/category-tabs-for-google/dlahcjmefibiedeecoegjilekaebchhl/related?hl=en.

It seems to be working fine, and provides some sorting capability (limited amount of colors, i.e., catagories).